# Display multiple rows one by one under same id from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table `hobbies` tables that has multiple rows under parent ID. In my view, my records are displayed altogether. But I want to display these row records one-by-one or individually.

**My Table:**

[image]

**Parent.php**

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function feature() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Feature::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**Feature.php**

```
class Feature extends Model
{

    public function feat()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function display($url)
{
    $parent = Parent::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();
    $feat = Feature::with(['feat','user'])->get();

    return view ('display', compact('parent', 'feat'));
}
```

**display.blade.php**

```
@foreach($feat as $show)
    <img alt="{{ $show->col_name }}" src="{{url($show->col_img) }}"/>
@endforeach
```

> I want to display like this
>   [image]

Comment: Where does the variable $colour come from? Is the shown table child of Feature? Which model does your table show?

Comment: Like Brotzka said, didn't you just make a mistake using the wrong variable? The `$colour->col_name` is now coming from some other place on the scope as supposed to the collection that is used in the `@foreach`

Comment: @Brotzka Feature model has that table. Now, I updated the question. BTW how can I display images one by one from multiple rows? Should I do on View part or on Controller part?

Comment: Do you want to display all images for product 4, product 5, product 6 and so on? I'm a little bit confused by the class `Parent`.. Is a Parent a Product? And do you want to show parent for parent and for each parent all features?

Comment: I want to display all images of product 4 in one page, product 5 on another page. I did that. But, I want to display these images on page whenever I want - one by one. Yes `Parent` is `Product`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to get a parent (or is it a product) by the given url. In your view you want to display all features attached/related to/with this parent.

First of all, change your Models as shown below (assuming your Models are stored under `app/`:

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function features() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Feature', 'product_id');
    }
}


class Feature extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Parent');
    }
}
```

Now it is enough to search for your parent in your controller:

```
public function display($url)
{
    $parent = Parent::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();
    $feature = Feature::where('parent_id', $parent->id)->first();
    return view ('display', ['parent' => $parent, 'feature' => $feature]);
}
```

Finally you can access your features in your template-file as shown below:

```
// Show your parent-information
<h1>{{ $parent->name }}</h1>

<img src="{{ $feature->col_img }}" alt="{{ $feature->col_name }}">
```

I hope that this is what you were searching for!

To display random images at the top, middle and bottom of your page, you could use [Laravel's array_random-function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-random):

```
@php
    // store your features in a temporary variable
    $features = $parent->features;

    // collect feature and remove it from array
    $feature1 = array_random($features);
    array_forget($features, $feature1);
    $feature2 = array_random($features);
    array_forget($features, $feature1);
    $feature3 = array_random($features);
@endphp

<!-- Top -->
<img src="{{ $feature1->col_img }}" alt="{{ $feature1->col_name }}">

<!-- Middle -->
<img src="{{ $feature2->col_img }}" alt="{{ $feature2->col_name }}">

<!-- Bottom -->
<img src="{{ $feature3->col_img }}" alt="{{ $feature3->col_name }}">
```

I don't know if Laravel's `array_random` works this way . So maybe you have to remove the returned item another way.

Comment: Yes. I did this. It shows all images of parent ID. But I want to display only one image from table row of that parentID. For example: from above table, I want to show only `images/o1.jpg` of parent id 4 instead of all 3images.

Comment: I've changed the code. Now you retrieve only one feature fitting your parent's id.

Comment: Yes, that worked for the first image. What if I want to display any random image from the row? One image at top of the page, another at middle & another at the bottom of the page? Is there any efficient & clean way?

Comment: You could collect all images like shown above. In your view you could use Laravel's helper function `array_random()` which return a random value from an array (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-random). Call this function on `$parent->features` in your template
    @php
        $img = array_random($parent->features)
    @endphp
More see in my answer ^^

Comment: It returns `array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`. Is it possible to display image one-by-one according to id? (I am Laravel newbie though)

Comment: So you have to transform your object to an array. Try something like `$features = $parent->features->toArray()`. maybe you have to to a little bit of research by yourself ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161287/discussion-between-universal-and-brotzka).